# create different class for different form in codenameone

Tags: forms, class, codenameone

I have 5 or more forms in codenameone app and I generally do all the functions in Statemachine .  And I want to do each function of each form in different class , how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a separate class and have the callback of the state machine invoke that class.